Which episode of South Park is this?
I recall an episode in which Mr. Mackey and Miss Chokesondick have sex after trying to teach the kids about sex, but ended up realising they barely knew about it themselves, which i think is what drove them to get it on.

Also, the confusion amongst the teachers caused the kids to become misinformed:

This escalated into some form of war since the girls were afraid that the boys will give them HIV. 
Whats the name of the episode, or at least, which season was it in?

I found the answer to this question by googling the exact quote you posted.

Which quote...?

The quote in the image. "Its even got a little reservoir at the end so you can pee in it".

Proper Condom Use (S05 E07)
The episode you describe is the seventh episode of the fifth season; "Proper Condom Use". It was first aired on the 1st of August, 2001. The episode is all about the school providing improper sexual education, in the same manner which you describe.
Due to improperly educating the children, the girls are convinced that they can contract STI1s from the boys, even without having sex. When the boys find out, they are not impressed, and as a result, there is a big battle in which several of the kids die.
Also, Mr. Mackey and Ms. Choksondik get it on. Good for them.

Reading through the plot on Wikipedia, all of the elements you remember are there:

"Mr. Mackey and Miss Chokesondick have sex after trying to teach the kids about sex.."

While Mr. Mackey and Miss Chokesondik prepare a future lesson plan, they admit to having fantasies about each other, and have sex.

... While preparing the lesson plan, Ms. Choksondik and Mr. Mackey become aroused by the sexual nature of their conversation, and admit to having sexual fantasies about each other. The two undress, and engage in unprotected sexual intercourse.



"..  but ended up realising they barely knew about it themselves.."

It is clear that Mr. Mackey knows very little, having last had sex 21 years prior. It is suggested that Miss Choksondik simply has a narrow view, and confuses the children by assuming that they already know a bit about what they are discussion.


Mr. Mackey tries to teach the fourth grade boys about a male anatomy and female anatomy and the mechanics of sexual intercourse. Not having had sex since he was 19, 21 years earlier, Mr. Mackey cannot teach the boys anything of use. Ms. Choksondik, intending to scare the girls into safe sex, spends her lesson teaching the girls about all the different types of STDs that they might catch if the boys are not wearing condoms, but leaves out the most important detail, that in order to catch these diseases, they would first need to have sex (presumably because she feels it seems so obvious).



"This escalated into some form of war since the girls were afraid that the boys will give them HIV."

In the episode, the girls think that the boys will give them STIs1, if they are not wearing protection. Eventually, they build a fort, and there is a battle involving Molotov cocktails and nail guns.

The girls, terrified by Ms. Choksondik's traumatizing lessons, build a massive fort to keep the boys out. The boys find where the girls are hiding and tell them to leave town in a siege reminiscent of Mad Max 2. The girls refuse and open fire (killing Kenny in the fusillade) and the boys attack. ... Meanwhile, the battle between the girls and boys leads to several casualties with Molotov Cocktails and rapid-fire nail-guns, thus drawing the attention of the adults and the parents, who get angry at the children for the conflict. 



1 When the episode aired, the correct term was STD. It has now been renamed as STI.
